# How to iterate an array of objects through each object element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to iterate an array of objects to display each object element in a table.

Thats my array:

```
     list: [
                {header: ['id', 'name', 'date', 'verified']},
                {body: [1, 'abc', '26-10-2019', true]}
            ]
```

I want to render a table in a vertical position like this:
[image]

That's how I'm trying to do:

```
const render = list.map((result, idx) => (
            <tr key={idx}>
                <td>{result.header}</td>                
                <td>{result.body}</td>                
            </tr>
        ))
```

But the result is

```
<tr>
   <td>id name date verified</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>1 abc 26-10-2019 true</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You need to loop over `result.header` and `result.body` as well

Comment: how long will the list array be ? it's really unpractical to do it this way.

Comment: @k.s. it's an array with 2 objects

Comment: @mr.abdo will it always be just an array with two objects ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to repeat the whole table, like this

```
const render = list[0].header.map((name, i) => <tr key={i}>
                <td>{name}</td>
                <td>{String(list[1].body[i])}</td>
            </tr>)
```

Comment: Tks for your help. I got this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` but I'm trying to solve it.

Comment: maybe the `list` variable is not defined on the initial load

Comment: or there will be an element not containing `header` property

Comment: It was my mistake. I fix it and I got this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: can you create a fiddle or codepen for your component?

Comment: I've updated your fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/2x3f5hqr/ and also updated my answer

Comment: Tku so much. Fantastic!!

Answer (score -3):

try:

```
      const render = list.map((result, idx) => (
        <tr key={idx}>
            <td>{result.header[idx].toString()}</td>                
            <td>{result.body[idx].toString()}</td>                
        </tr>
      ))
```

Comment: I got this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: why are you using `toString()` here?

Comment: just to be sure integers, array and whatnot are converted to string